# restrict key input to prevent spamming

Tags: java, javafx

I have a canvas in my scrollPane, in which I draw data based on the time that is currently shown. The position can be changed with the left and right arrow keys on the keyboard. The problem is, that spamming the key by holding them down, moves the position of the scrollPane too fast. So what I am thinking about is to restrict the input like waiting 100ms or something like that before the position changes again. I tried it with Thread.Sleep(100) but I would prefer a solution without it.

```
scrollPane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {

    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
    {
       Thread.sleep(100);
       drawNextPosition();
    }
    else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
    {
       Thread.sleep(100);
       drawPreviousPosition();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Timeline` to refresh the scene and simply save the state of the keys in the event handler:

```
private KeyCode key;

private final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), evt -> {
    switch (key) {
        case RIGHT:
            drawNextPosition();
        break;
        case LEFT:
            drawPreviousPosition();
        break;
    }
});

private void keyDown(KeyCode code) {
    switch (code) {
        case LEFT:
        case RIGHT:
            // start timeline or continue playing
            timeline.play();
            key = code;
    }

}

private void keyUp(KeyCode code) {
    if (code == key) {
        // stop animation, if key for current direction is released
        timeline.stop();
        key = null;
    }
}
```

```
scrollPane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> keyDown(e.getCode()));
scrollPane.setOnKeyReleased(e -> keyUp(e.getCode()));
```

Comment: If you want to have a smoother animation, you can alternatively use an [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html). With an AnimationTimer you can calculate how much time has passed since the last rendering of your scene and by that determine the amount of movement inside your `drawNextPosition()` and `drawPreviousPosition()`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Timestamp variable.
Initiate the variable.

```
var last_updated = new Date().getTime();
```

And

```
if(new Date().getTime() > last_updated + 100) {
  drawNewPosition();
  last_updated = new Date().getTime();
}
```